# how to remove null pointerException in android?

Tags: android

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(!ConstantVariable.isfilterOccured){
             View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem, null);
            }

            final TextView platFormName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_platform);

            final TextView schDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_schDepart);
            final TextView expDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expectdepart);
            final TextView arrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_arrival);
            final TextView exparrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expertarrival);
            final TextView stationName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_stationName);
            final ImageView alertStatusImage = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.alertStatus);

            final String platformValue = deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getPlatformNo();
            final String schDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getSchDepart();
            final String schExpectValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getExpDepart();
            final String arrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
            final String exparrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
           String stationNameValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestinationStation().getStationName();
           if(deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getAlertsId()!=0){
               alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }else {
               alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
           }


            platFormName.setText(platformValue);

            schDepart.setText(schDepartValue);
            expDepart.setText(schExpectValue);
            arrival.setText(arrivalValue);
            exparrival.setText(exparrivalValue);
            stationName.setText(stationNameValue);
            if (position%2==0) {
                Log.d("--------", "old");
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            } else {
                Log.d("--------", "even");

                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
            }
            return v;
         }else {
             View vv = convertView;

                if (vv == null) {
                    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    vv = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filterdashboard, null);
                }

                final TextView platFormName = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.platFormId);

                final TextView destinationName = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.destinationStationName);
                final TextView filterStationName = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.filterStationNameId);
                final TextView toSchArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.toschArrivalID);
                final TextView toExpArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.toExpArrivalID);
                final TextView destinationSchArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.destSchArrivalID);
                final TextView destinationExpArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.destExpArrivalID);

                final TextView schDepart = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.schDepartID);
                final TextView expDepart = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.expDepartID);

                final ImageView alertStatusImage = (ImageView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.alertStatus);

                final String platformValue = deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getPlatformNo();
                final String toSchArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getToSchArrival();
                final String toExpArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getToExpArrival();
                final String destSchArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
                final String destExpArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestExpArrival();


                final String schDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getSchDepart();
                final String expDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getExpDepart();
               String destinationStationNamValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestinationStation().getStationName();
               String filterStationNameValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getFilteredStation().getStationName();

               if(deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getAlertsId()!=0){
                   alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }else {
                   alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
               }


                platFormName.setText(platformValue);

                destinationName.setText(destinationStationNamValue);
                filterStationName.setText(filterStationNameValue);
                toSchArrival.setText(toSchArrivalValue);
                toExpArrival.setText(toExpArrivalValue);
                destinationSchArrival.setText(destSchArrivalValue);
                destinationExpArrival.setText(destExpArrivalValue);
                schDepart.setText(schDepartValue);
                expDepart.setText(expDepartValue);



                if (position%2==0) {
                    Log.d("--------", "old");
                    vv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                } else {
                    Log.d("--------", "even");

                    vv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
                }
                return vv;
         }
    }
```

Hi
I am getting null pointer exception.I know this will come when I am trying to access something from null value .But I don't know how to remove that .I will explain my problem .I have a list view I need to show data on listview which is coming from service.Actully I take one condition   **if(!ConstantVariable.isfilterOccured){** intially **isfilterOccured** is false .it goes inside this condition

```
if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem, null);
                }
```

But when I call another webservice **if(!ConstantVariable.isfilterOccured){** intially **isfilterOccured** is **true**  why it is not going inside the condition that is the reason I am getting null.

```
View vv = convertView;

                    if (vv == null) {
                        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        vv = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filterdashboard, null);
                    }
```

then it not find this item

```
  final TextView platFormName = (TextView) vv
                            .findViewById(R.id.platFormId);
```

**please see update:**

```
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.firstgroup.components.DepartureListAdapter.getView(DepartureListAdapter.java:156)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2012)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-02 06:42:30.634: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting exception on this line

**platFormName.setText(platformValue);**

because **platFormName** is null .I think it is null because it id not use this xml

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        vv = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filterdashboard, null);
```

platFormId defined in this filterdashboard.xml

working like that

```
public class DepartureListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<Deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto;
    private Context context;
    public DepartureListAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<Deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto){
        this.deparaturedaseboarddto=deparaturedaseboarddto;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(!ConstantVariable.isfilterOccured){
             View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem, null);
            }

            final TextView platFormName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_platform);

            final TextView schDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_schDepart);
            final TextView expDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expectdepart);
            final TextView arrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_arrival);
            final TextView exparrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expertarrival);
            final TextView stationName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_stationName);
            final ImageView alertStatusImage = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.alertStatus);

            final String platformValue = deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getPlatformNo();
            final String schDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getSchDepart();
            final String schExpectValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getExpDepart();
            final String arrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
            final String exparrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
           String stationNameValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestinationStation().getStationName();
           if(deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getAlertsId()!=0){
               alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }else {
               alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
           }


            platFormName.setText(platformValue);

            schDepart.setText(schDepartValue);
            expDepart.setText(schExpectValue);
            arrival.setText(arrivalValue);
            exparrival.setText(exparrivalValue);
            stationName.setText(stationNameValue);
            if (position%2==0) {
                Log.d("--------", "old");
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            } else {
                Log.d("--------", "even");

                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
            }
            return v;
         }else {
             View vv = convertView;

//              if (vv == null) {
//                  LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
//                          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//                  vv = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filterdashboard, null);
//              }
             LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              vv = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filterdashboard, null);

                final TextView platFormName = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.platFormId);

                final TextView destinationName = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.destinationStationName);
                final TextView filterStationName = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.filterStationNameId);
                final TextView toSchArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.toschArrivalID);
                final TextView toExpArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.toExpArrivalID);
                final TextView destinationSchArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.destSchArrivalID);
                final TextView destinationExpArrival = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.destExpArrivalID);

                final TextView schDepart = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.schDepartID);
                final TextView expDepart = (TextView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.expDepartID);

                final ImageView alertStatusImage = (ImageView) vv
                        .findViewById(R.id.alertStatusImage);

                final String platformValue = deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getPlatformNo();
                final String toSchArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getToSchArrival();
                final String toExpArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getToExpArrival();
                final String destSchArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
                final String destExpArrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestExpArrival();


                final String schDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getSchDepart();
                final String expDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getExpDepart();
               String destinationStationNamValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestinationStation().getStationName();
               String filterStationNameValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getFilteredStation().getStationName();

               if(deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getAlertsId()!=0){
                   alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }else {
                   alertStatusImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
               }


                platFormName.setText(platformValue);

                destinationName.setText(destinationStationNamValue);
                filterStationName.setText(filterStationNameValue);
                toSchArrival.setText(toSchArrivalValue);
                toExpArrival.setText(toExpArrivalValue);
                destinationSchArrival.setText(destSchArrivalValue);
                destinationExpArrival.setText(destExpArrivalValue);
                schDepart.setText(schDepartValue);
                expDepart.setText(expDepartValue);



                if (position%2==0) {
                    Log.d("--------", "old");
                    vv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                } else {
                    Log.d("--------", "even");

                    vv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
                }
                return vv;
         }
    }

    public void referhList( ArrayList<Deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto){
        this.deparaturedaseboarddto=deparaturedaseboarddto;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}


private void showFilterWebDashBoard(String response) {
        Log.d("--",response);
        ConstantVariable.isfilterOccured=true;
        DepartureHolder localdata = new Gson().fromJson(response, DepartureHolder.class);
        data=localdata;

        adapter.referhList(data.getData());
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the text of the thrown NPE? It's not clear from your question which object is null.

Comment: Please, post your logcat output.

Comment: ok I will tell you.see more update...I will give example what I want to say.Let take I am getting data from webservice 1 to 100 numbers ..I want to display to listfield.I am able to do that using (a.xml) a.xml (for UI)..But there is another button in view on click that button it call webservice give data 101 to 200.Now I want to show data on list using same adapter but different xml file (b.xml).problem is that it not load b.xml ..

Comment: @JuniorBuckeridge did you find anything

Comment: If it is not a long list, could you try not using convertView?

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung please check update is it a good way to do this task

Comment: If it is working, then it is good. But if you want to optimize your code, you can: avoid duplicate code by create another method for processing returned view. Smoother list with holder pattern: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a layout for the list items that contains both of your current layouts **R.layout.row_listitem** and **R.layout.filterdashboard** (so now you'll inflate **R.layout.merged_layouts**), and based on

```
ConstantVariable.isfilterOccured
```

you can change visibility of the corresponding container layout, and keep the view reusability (you could even add a ViewHolder pattern for boosting performance).

Hope it helps.

Comment: please check update ..I am able to do like that ..it working ..is it a best way to do that

Comment: A better way is how I suggested. You can reuse the views and even add a ViewHolder pattern to increase performance. Add both of your layouts to a single xml file, and just toggle visibility depending on the variable.

Comment: could you please give example actually i am new in android